# Estoy intenando entender este código en Python n = list(n)

Tags: python

Estoy intentando entender este código el cúal me permite convertir binarios a decimales pero me encuentro con este pequeño código en dónde se utiliza la siguiente sintáxis

```
def to_decimal(n):
     """Función que convierte un número binario en decimal.
     Parámetros:
          - n: Es una cadena de ceros y unos.
     Devuelve:
          El número decimal correspondiente a n.
     """
     n = list(n)
     n.reverse()
     decimal = 0
     for i in range(len(n)):
         decimal += int(n[i]) * 2 ** i
     return decimal
```

La parte que no entiendo es la de n = list(n), porque no entiendo su funcionamiento bien alguien me podría pasar el link dónde se explica en la página de W3Schools?

Comment: Conviertes n, que es "101" (5 en binario) por ejemplo, a una lista `{1,0,1}` y entonces haces un loop multiplicando cada uno de esos números por 2 y elevándolo a `i`, es decir, 1 * 2^0 *(1)* + 0 * 2^1 *(0)* + 1 * 2^1 *(4)*, y el resultado lo vas sumando a `decimal`, obteniendo así un valor de 5 :). Tal como menciona @Alfabravo, el código está mal indentado... imagino que ha sido un error al copiar/pegar, puesto que tal cual está ahí la función está incorrectamente declarada y no funcionaría! Si ha sido error al copiar y pegar, por favor edita la pregunta y arréglalo... si no, ahí está el error

Comment: ese código está mal indentado. Revisa para que puedas recibir una realimentación oportuna; la indentación en python es crucial

Answer (score 0):

Vale, creo ya tengo el funcionamiento de n = list(n), lo que hice fue apuntar con el cursor al código n = list(n) y me arrojo la información que necesitaba entender

Comment: Hola Linky, intenta actualizar tu pregunta en vez de añadir a más información como respuesta (sin que lo sea).

Answer (score 0):

En tu función recibes una cadena de cero y unos como ésta:

```
"10011"
```

Una cadena es un iterable. Los iterables se pueden convertir en listas usando la función `list`. Entonces, esta instrucción

```
n = list(n)
```

transforma la cadena en esta lista:

```
['1', '0', '0', '1', '1']
```

Como es una lista, puedo recorrerla tomando cada elemento de la lista, que sería cada digito binario del valor recibido:

```
def to_decimal(n):
    decimal = 0
    for digito in list(n):
        decimal = decimal * 2 + int(digito)

    return decimal
```

Hay varias simplificaciones que se pueden hacer. No es necesario dar vuelta la lista, basta recorrerla de digito más significativo a menos significativo.

El `for` recorre los digitos binarios uno a uno. En cada iteración tomamos el valor acumulado en `decimal` y lo multiplicamos por dos antes de agregar otro digito por la derecha.

**Demo**

```
print(to_decimal("10"))
print(to_decimal("1010"))
print(to_decimal("110011"))
```

produce:

```
2
10
51
```